# Google Vision Java Client Batch Request Response Identification

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, bulk, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to make a batch request to Google Vision Text Detection API. So far, I put the paths of the images into a list, make the batch request and get the responses. However, I cannot determine which result belongs to which image. To do this, I tried to put an ID into the request, and when I get the result back, I would compare the IDs. However, I cannot put any custom field into the request. Is there something wrong with my approach? How can I know which response belongs to which image?

Here is the code I use for these requests:

```
private Vision vision;
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "ProjectName";

public static Vision getVisionService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream
            (new FileInputStream("/project-key.json"))
            .createScoped(VisionScopes.all());
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    return new Vision.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}
/**
 * Gets up to {@code maxResults} text annotations for images stored at {@code paths}.
 */
public List<String> detectText(List<Path> paths) {
    ImmutableList.Builder<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = ImmutableList.builder();

    try {
        for (Path path : paths) {
            byte[] data;
            data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            requests.add(
                    new AnnotateImageRequest()
                    .setImage(new Image().encodeContent(data))
                    .setFeatures(ImmutableList.of(
                            new Feature()
                            .setType("TEXT_DETECTION")
                            .setMaxResults(10))));
        }

        Vision.Images.Annotate annotate =
                vision.images()
                .annotate(new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest().setRequests(requests.build()));
        // Due to a bug: requests to Vision API containing large images fail when GZipped.
        annotate.setDisableGZipContent(true);
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse batchResponse = annotate.execute();
        assert batchResponse.getResponses().size() == paths.size();

        List<String> output = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            AnnotateImageResponse response = batchResponse.getResponses().get(i);
            if(response != null && response.getTextAnnotations() != null){
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                String result = getDescriptionFromJson(response.getTextAnnotations().toString());
                System.out.println(response.get("customField"));
                output.add(result);
            }
        }
        return output;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured: " + ex);
        return null;
    }
}

public String getDescriptionFromJson(String json){
    JSONArray results = new JSONArray(json);
    JSONObject result = (JSONObject) results.get(0);
    return result.getString("description");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GoogleVisionQueryHelper g = new GoogleVisionQueryHelper();

    try {
        g.vision = getVisionService();
        List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

        String directory = "/images";

        File[] files = new File(directory).listFiles();
        for(File file : files){
          if(file.isFile() && !file.getName().contains("DS_Store") && !file.getName().startsWith(".")){
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            paths.add(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
          }
        }           
        System.out.println("Starting...");

        for(String s: g.detectText(paths)){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi bro, can you give me some help? My program will stuck in 
        `BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.images()
                .annotate(requestBatch)
                .setDisableGZipContent(true)
                .execute();`
Do you know the reason? I am totally new to Google cloud vision api
I suspect the correct of the url of request, because it always show `https://vision.googleapis.com`, rather than `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=`

Answer (score 1):

BatchAnnotateImageResponse holds the responses List in the same order as the requests List in BatchAnnotateImageRequest.

Comment: how do you know that?